# dropdown hidden behind divs in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, css, drop-down-menu, suckerfish

Hi I've finally got Suckerfish working and styled but in IE7 it is hidden behind the divs below it. [See the dropdown on the 'Your Video/Pics' button here.](http://www.smokinhot.com.au/)

I know usually a z-index would solve the issue but in this case it seems not. Can anyone help?

Don't worry this site is not supposed to work in IE6 ;)

Comment: You should probably put a NSFW tag on that link ;)

Comment: Yes sorry it's a lingerie shop website, don't worry though it's all above board!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

For IE, the entire block has to have a higher z-index than the block below it.

Comment: Thanks Jeffery To, you are right and your solution makes perfect sense. I should have thought of that ;), thanks again, much appreciated :)